# Angular 2 App - Debugging Protractor Code

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, protractor

Does anybody actually know how to debug protractor code for an angular 2 application? I have npm version 8 installed and the 'browser.pause()' function has now been removed in this version. Apparently I need to use 'debugger'. I have tried adding 'debugger;' to my code, but when my code reached this section in the code it just runs straight through it, without stopping.

I have spent days trying to find documentation on this, but everything seems to either be related to angularJS or plane javascript applications. Please could somebody end my misery and tell me how to debug my angular 2 protractor e2e testing code?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md